# Inject non-form element into dynamic Django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Is it possible to inject a non-form element into a dynamic Django form's context?  I have a "Delete user photos" form that I want to contain a thumbnail image of each user with a BooleanField checkbox and label right below it:

```
+------------+
|            |
|   photo    |
|            |
+------------+
[x]  Delete <username>'s photos
```

Right now I know how to create the dynamic checkboxes and their labels but I'm not sure how to go about adding each user's photo.  As can be seen from my code below, the name attribute of each HTML input tag will contain the user's ID and I'll examine this attribute when the user submits the form to determine whether to delete their photos or not.  I'd like to insert an  tag just above each input tag that links to the user's profile photo.  The image tag's "src" attribute will contain the user's ID which creates the link to their photo.  Is there a way to "inject" this non-form image tag into the context of this dynamic form in order to render an image tag just above each checkbox input tag?

Thanks.

```
# views.py
def remove_access_to_private_photos(request, template):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RemovePrivatePhotoAccessForm(request.POST, this_user_id=request.user.id)
        if form.is_valid():
            for name, value in form.cleaned_data.items():
                if value == True:
                    # Profile links to User via a OneToOneField
                    this_user = Profile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
                    other_user = Profile.objects.get(user_id=name)
                    this_user.remove_private_access(other_user_prof)
        return redirect('photos-home')
    else:
        form = RemovePrivatePhotoAccessForm(this_user_id=request.user.id)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)

# models.py
class RemovePrivatePhotoAccessForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        this_user_id = kwargs.pop('this_user_id')
        super(RemovePrivatePhotoAccessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=this_user_id)
        user_prof = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        other_user_id_list = user_prof.gave_private_access().values_list('user_id', flat=True)
        for id in other_user_id_list:
            other_user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
            self.fields[str(id)] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
            self.fields[str(id)].label = mark_safe('<a href="/photos/delete/%s/%s">%s</a>') % (id, this_user_id, other_user.username)

# delete_photos.html
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}

        {# I'D LIKE TO PUT <IMG> TAG HERE #}
        {{ field }} Delete {{ field.label|safe }}'s photos

    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: A form is just a class. it can have any attribute you want to assign via args or kwargs.

Comment: Right, but I don't understand how I'd render the image in the case where it's not a part of the form's context.  My template is saying, "for field in form..."  If the image is not "form.field" or "form.label", how would you inject it into a dynamic form?

Comment: I'll add an example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this problem.  First I created a custom template tag:

```
    # photos/templatetags/photos_extras.py
    from django import template
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

    register = template.Library()

    @register.simple_tag
    def render_image(uid):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        src_string = ''.join([
            '/photos/',
            user.username, '_',
            user.profile.image_id,
            '_thumb.jpg'])
        img_tag = ''.join([
            '<img src="',
            src_string,
            '" alt="',
            user.username,
            '" />'])
        return mark_safe(img_tag)
```

I then inserted the custom template tag into my template.  field.name contains the desired user's user ID, and render_image returns the desired HTML img tag.

```
# delete_photos.html
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}

        {% render_image field.name %}
        {{ field }} Delete {{ field.label|safe }}'s photos

    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A form field is just a class, so you can add whatever properties you need when or after you instantiate it. Your view remains unchanged given this example code.

```
# forms.py
from .models import Profile  # or whatever


class RemovePrivatePhotoAccessForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id')

        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        other_profiles = user_profile.gave_private_access()

        for profile in other_profiles:
            id = str(profile.id)
            field = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
            field.label = mark_safe('<a href="/photos/delete/%s/%s">%s</a>') % (id, user_profile.id, profile.username)
            field.photo = profile.photo
            self.fields[id] = field

        super(RemovePrivatePhotoAccessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)



# delete_photos.html
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}

        <img src="{{ field.photo.url }}" />
        {{ field }} Delete {{ field.label|safe }}'s photos

    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon but this doesn't appear to work.  Since this is a dynamic form, there will be one field and field label for each user whose photos can be deleted.  Setting self.user_photo only captures the photo of the last user in the list, not the photo of each user in the list.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-understood your question. I've updated my answer for you

Comment: Thanks Brandon but I wasn't able to get your code to work.  If I debug and  break inside the form, I can see field.photo being set but the template isn't rendering it.  I did "View source" in my browser and it's not there.  I did manage to solve the problem on my own this afternoon using a custom template tag.  I'll post my code shortly.